# Enrich Serlilogs with unique value per hangfire job

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, hangfire, serilog

I'm using Hangfire for background jobs, and Serilog for logging. I'm trying to enrich my serilogs with a `TrackingId` so that all logs from a specific Hangfire job will have the same `TrackingId` that I can filter on.

I configure Serilog like this in `Startup.cs`:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
    .WriteTo.Seq(serverUrl: serverUrl, apiKey: apiKey)

    // Enrich the logs with a tracking id. Will be a new value per request
    .Enrich.WithProperty("TrackingId", Guid.NewGuid())

    .CreateLogger();
```

And I enqueue jobs like this:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<MyService>(myService => myService.DoIt(someParameter));
```

But doing like this will not set a separate `TrackingId` per Hangfire job. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: I've had a look at the Hangfire API and can't find a way to do this easily; adding a "server filter" seems like it might work. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I ended up pulling this off using the server/client filter and `GlobalJobFilters` registration shown below.  One annoying issue I ran into is that the `AutomaticRetryAttribute` is added by default to the `GlobalJobFilters` collection, and that class [will log errors for failed jobs](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/AutomaticRetryAttribute.cs#L169) without knowledge of the Serilog LogContext created in our custom `JobLoggerAttribute`.  Personally, I know I will only allow manual retry, so I just removed that attribute and handled the error within the `IServerFilter.OnPerformed` method.  Check the end of my post to see how to remove it if that works for you.

If you are going to allow automatic retry, then you will need to: 1) create a custom attribute that decorates the `AutomaticRetryAttribute` and makes it aware of a custom LogContext, 2) again remove the default `AutomaticRetryAttribute` from the `GlobalJobFilters` collection, and 3) add your decorator attribute to the collection.

```
public class JobLoggerAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IClientFilter, IServerFilter
{
    private ILogger _log;

    public void OnCreating(CreatingContext filterContext)
    {
        _log = GetLogger();

        _log.Information("Job is being created for {JobType} with arguments {JobArguments}", filterContext.Job.Type.Name, filterContext.Job.Args);
    }

    public void OnCreated(CreatedContext filterContext)
    {
        _log.Information("Job {JobId} has been created.", filterContext.BackgroundJob.Id);
    }

    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (_log == null)
            _log = GetLogger();

        _log.Information("Job {JobId} is performing.", filterContext.BackgroundJob.Id);
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
    {
        _log.Information("Job {JobId} has performed.", filterContext.BackgroundJob.Id);

        if (filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            _log.Error(
                filterContext.Exception,
                "Job {JobId} failed due to an exception.",
                filterContext.BackgroundJob.Id);
        }

        _log = null;
    }

    private ILogger GetLogger()
    {
        return Log.ForContext(GetType()).ForContext("HangfireRequestId", Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}
```

And the registration...

```
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new JobLoggerAttribute());
```

Removing the `AutomaticRetryAttribute`...

```
var automaticRetryFilter = GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Where(x => x.Instance is AutomaticRetryAttribute).Single();
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Remove(automaticRetryFilter.Instance);
```

Comment: How is this actually thread-safe? The _log field is shared across worker threads.