# Hangfire: add JobId globally for logging to Serilog

Tags: c#, serilog, hangfire

I am trying to add the Hangfire JobId (and other properties) to all of my jobs without having to add it to each job method.

In Startup.cs I added a promising filter solution however I don't know how to apply it to my test method and I am not even sure if this is the right way to do it.

Startup.cs

```
...
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new JobLoggerAttribute());
```

**JobLoggerAttribute** class - from here:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771480/enrich-serlilogs-with-unique-value-per-hangfire-job)

The task for me is to put the JobId where the column cell is currently blank without having to add it to my Test method manually:
[image]

Program.cs (globally defined Logger):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .WriteTo.Elasticsearch....
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .CreateLogger();
```

Because I also want to retrieve method name etc. I added this class to call the Here method in my jobs.

LoggerExtensions.cs:

```
    public static class LoggerExtensions
    {
        public static ILogger Here(this ILogger logger,
            [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
            [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
            [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0
            )
        {
            return logger
                .ForContext("MemberName", memberName)
                .ForContext("FilePath", sourceFilePath)
                .ForContext("LineNumber", sourceLineNumber)
                ;
        }
    }
```

RunTestTask:

```
public void RunTestTask(PerformContext context)
        {

            // instead of having to write this line in all methods
            // LogContext.PushProperty("JobId", context.BackgroundJob.Id);
            Log.Logger.Here().Information(string.Format("Serilog: Hanfire Job {1} Scheduled at {0}", DateTime.Now, context.BackgroundJob.Id));
        }
```

Job Enqueue:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => new Jobs.Test.TestService().RunTestTask(null));
```

Hoping for tips and tricks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

it is too late to answer this question , also I am not an expert in both tools (Hangfire & Serilog), in my case , I used Serilog in combination with Seq and my goal was to add  Job Id property to all logs written from Hangfire Job, and here is the code that I used to achieve this

```
public class CustomBackgroundJobPerformer : IBackgroundJobPerformer
{
    private readonly BackgroundJobPerformer _innerPerformer;

    public CustomBackgroundJobPerformer(BackgroundJobPerformer innerPerformer)
    {
        _innerPerformer = innerPerformer;
    }

    public object Perform(PerformContext context)
    {
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("JobId", context.BackgroundJob.Id))
        {
            return _innerPerformer.Perform(context);
        }
    }
}
```

now we need to register it , but based on this [link](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1375#issuecomment-475641751) ,to apply our change, we need to register all the interfaces – IBackgroundJobFactory, IBackgroundJobStateChanger and IBackgroundJobPerformer

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      ...
       services.TryAddSingleton<IBackgroundJobFactory>(x => new BackgroundJobFactory(x.GetRequiredService<IJobFilterProvider>()));

        services.TryAddSingleton<IBackgroundJobPerformer>(x => new CustomBackgroundJobPerformer(
            new BackgroundJobPerformer(
                x.GetRequiredService<IJobFilterProvider>(),
                x.GetRequiredService<JobActivator>(),
                TaskScheduler.Default)));

        services.TryAddSingleton<IBackgroundJobStateChanger>(x => 
                new BackgroundJobStateChanger(x.GetRequiredService<IJobFilterProvider>()));

        ...
      }
```